# Sum values from different ng-repeat Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to sum three values from different ng-repeat in my view, this is what I have.

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in data1">
  <td>a.num1</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="b in data2">
  <td>b.num2</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="c in data3">
  <td>c.num3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>(Here I want to print the sum of the three values)</td>
</tr>
```

I have this in my controller.

```
    $scope.data1 = [
        {
          "num1": 1,
        }
    ]
    $scope.data2 = [
         {
           "num2": 2,
         }
    ]

    $scope.data3 = [
        {
           "num3": 3,
        }
   ]
```

The binding is ok, I print the values coming from each ng-repeat but I need to sum does values and print the result in the last

Some help with this will be great!

Comment: could you also please post your `angularjs` code and some sample data?

Comment: Hi, I dont have a fiddle because I cant access from the network Im connected to, I update my question and put the data I have, it's a small example.

Comment: You should really just do this in a function in the controller (or better still in a service/factory that deals with fetching the data if it only needs to happen when new data is fetched).  When you do things with interpolation {{}} in the view you create a watcher and on every digest the expression in the {{}} is re-evaluated this results in poor performance as you continue to add more watchers and digests are triggered by anything that changes the model and needs to make the view update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

//in your controller side added this method

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.data1, function(data1) { 
        total += data1.num1;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.data2, function(data2) { 
        total += data2.num2;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.data3, function(data3) { 
        total += data3.num3;
    }
    return total;
}


<td>{{ getTotal() }}</td>//Here is the total value
```

Comment: Check the docs on ng-init it should only be used for aliasing properties for ng-repeat, this logic should just be done in JS somewhere (controller or some angular provider).  I'll remove my down-vote if you get rid of the ng-repeat and set that up in the controller (will switch it to an up-vote), but as is think it's not good advice.

Comment: This sort of logic doesn't belong in the view ... it should be done in controller. Doing it in view is horribly inefficient

Comment: @BilasSarker No problem retracted my down-vote and up-voted now... using ng-init or just generally trying to do a lot of logic in expressions is just a bad thing in the long run.  Works fine for simple little samples but kills performance on real life apps.  Ideally can also use {{::oneTimeDataBinding}} with the two colons if you only care once the value evaluates to something other than undefined (it doesn't change after it's filled).

Answer (score 3):

In your controller do this :

```
$scope.sum = $scope.data1[0].num1 + $scope.data2[0].num2 + $scope.data3[0].num3;
```

And assign the sum in td  as below:

```
<tr><td>{{sum}}</td></tr>
```

Comment: It is not the right way that you set fixed index and get summations.

Answer (score 1):

you also can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to access value outside ng-repeat

**like this**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="a in data1">
      <td>{{a.num1}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="b in data2">
      <td>{{b.num2}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end>
    <td>{{a.num1 + b.num2}} </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
</table>
```

for more information [ng-repeat-start](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points)

Answer (score 1):

This question may have been already answered but this may help. its more of a design pattern than an answer. it does involve rewriting some of your code.

By organizing data around one object you have more flexibility when it comes to dynamically creating / mutating data.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('bazContoller',function($scope){

let things = { //controller name or namespace
      enums:{ //enumerable's used by the controller
        data1:[ 
          { "num": 1 }
        ],
        data2:[ 
          { "num": 2 }
        ],
        data3:[ 
          { "num": 67 }
        ]
      },
  
      sum(){
      return Object.keys(this.enums).map(item => this.enums[item])
        .reduce((start ,item)=>start += item[0].num,0);
      }
  }

  Object.assign(this ,things) ; //controller as 
  //$scope['bazContoller'] = things; //$scope
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='bazContoller as baz'>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="a in baz.enums.data1">
      <td>{{a.num}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="b in baz.enums.data2">
      <td>{{b.num}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in baz.enums.data3">
      <td>{{c.num}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SUM: {{baz.sum()}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  
  </div>
</div>
```